# Improve VLC quality on WMV, AVI etc?

Tags: vlc, mediaplayer, video

OKay I've noticed that when I play an WMV on my Mac using VLC player the quality is terrible in comparison when i play it on Windows

I have tried "unchecking skip frames" on VLC, but no change at all

Anyone have any idea how to fix this on VLC?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

More a sidestep than a workaround but have you considering using [Flip4Mac](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/products/windows-media-player/wmcomponents) to play WMV's in Quicktime rather than use VLC?

if you can lose the extra functionality you get from VLC, the playback is much better.